# How to write HQL query to select all columns using * in oracle?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to select all columns from oracle DB using query : 
**SELECT  r.* ,  COUNT(*) OVER () TOTAL_COUNT FROM (select tables_columns from table) r**

I am able to execute this using **session.createSQLQuery(query)** but i need to use hibernate query **session.createQuery(hql)** to execute my sql query, here i am facing issue. the issue is hibernate not able to recognize  * and 'OVER' keyword. Hibernate doesn't understand r.*

How can i use hibernate query to do this operation ?

one way is to select all columns using ' r.column_name for all columns' but i need to use something similar to SQL query.

Comment: You can't. HQL doesn't support such queries.

Comment: I am making this change to improve performance. there is no way ?

Comment: Why do you thing using HQL, that would be translated to SQL and then executed by the database, would be more efficient that executing SQL directly?

Comment: I read this in tutorialspoint and other places as well "Although you can use SQL statements directly with Hibernate using Native SQL but I would recommend to use HQL whenever possible to avoid database portability hassles, and to take advantage of Hibernate's SQL generation and caching strategies."